# I cannot get default in sql to work

Tags: php, sql, default

I am having an issue with sql right now; I have gave a value a default so if the field is left empty when the user submit, but it is not working. When the user submits an empty field to leave a comment instead of it default to anon it does nothing. Also, in the datebase the field is empty.

```
name VARCHAR (50) default 'anon',


$name=   $_POST['name'];
$title=  sha1($_POST['title']);
$texts= $_POST['texts'];
$forum_id = $_POST['forum_id'];

$name = str_replace("'","''",$name);
$title = str_replace("'","''",$title);
$title = str_replace("b074acd521","STREAMER",$title);
$texts = str_replace("'","''",$texts);

$title = substr($title,0,8);

$sql = "INSERT INTO post (name,title, texts, forum_id) VALUES ('$name', '$title', '$texts', '$forum_id')";
mysqli_query($conn1, $sql) or die('Error inserting to database.');
mysqli_close($conn1);

header('Location: requests.php');
```

Is there another way to do it or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: It would help if you included the SQL you used to create the table

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "it does nothing"? Is there an error, does an empty value get inserted, or does nothing get inserted, but with no error? Please show both the SQL DDL and your code.

Comment: Knowing which SQL you are using (mysql, sql server, etc) would be helpful as well.

Comment: Here is the code http://pastebin.com/3sgBE8Ew here is the site where it is having the issue http://www.vidyasocks.com/forums.php?id=2&id=2    I am also having another problem when I leave the id field empty it still generates a hash for it.

Comment: A default value only gets applied when you don't mention the field in your `INSERT` query.

Comment: mysql.. okay jack, so what can I do then?

Comment: Don't mention it in the query

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query your using will not insert the default value from your database because you are specifying a value for `name` (even if that value is an empty string, or null) :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO post (name,title, texts, forum_id) VALUES ('$name', '$title', '$texts', '$forum_id')";
```

Instead if you want the default value to be inserted into the `name` field you must not specify the `name` column in the insert statement :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO post (title, texts, forum_id) VALUES ('$title', '$texts', '$forum_id')";
```

In SQL query you can specify for which fields, values will be provided in the query and remaining fields from the table would contain default value (in case of `AUTO_INCREMENT`, the next integer value will be used).

Answer (score 0):

Where you given the default value directly applied in SQL?  the value left in DB ultimately is what exactly you passed to DB server by SQL way, or just you defined a variable where if it don't accept a value from user then use the default value instead, please try to debug this to insure the value was handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

while insert the values you shouldn't give the column which you set default value
below Example explain it...Try like this...

```
create table er(id int,name char(10),gender char(2)default 'M')
```

Here i took gender as default 
now i insert the values

```
 insert into er (id,name)values(1,'poda')

 select * from er
```